# Mobile SDK 3.2 Logout Issue - Network action must have an instance hosts

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

I recently upgraded one of my iOS apps to Mobile SDK 3.2.

Everything generally works okay but I'm seeing this weird error message when user logs out -

```
Network action must have an instance hosts
```

Has anyone else seen this? How do you work around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is actually a [known issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/issues/1014) and has subsequently been fixed. You can also view the code changes for this fixed ticket [here](https://github.com/Taptera/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/commit/ee9756bd5fda2cedffede7711f38ed5ae3d69197).

This was occuring earlier because the flow was missing handling for unique subscribers as a key - `kSFUserAccountKey`

This is the crucial block

```
(void)userWillLogOutNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
  SFUserAccount *userAccount = notification.userInfo[kSFUserAccountKey];
    [[self class] cleanupNetworkForUserAccount:userAccount];
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav !!! +1 from me .Thank you for amazing contribution to the community